# Diode vs diode-connected transistor

Tags: transistors, diodes, integrated-circuit

Are there any differencies in functionality between those two or any advantages of one over the other?
The only thing that comes to mind why someone would use diode-connected transistors over diodes is if, for example, the whole integrated circuit technology is based on transistors and it's easier and more cost-friendly to just configure some of them as diodes when it's needed, other than integrating a diode in the circuit. Or, if transistors are more temperature resistant than diodes?
Are there any other differencies?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Are you talking about DTL vs TTL?

Comment: @Oldfart I'm confused too. Search the term "diode-connected transistor" and you will see.

Comment: @LongPham Your first comment answered my question. Thanks

Comment: It's funny that wiki pointed me back to EE.SE.